# How does one program in a tag system?

Tags: turing-machines, programming-languages, computation-models

I've played with 2-tag systems a bit and read all about tag/lag systems. They're great for experimenting with computation, and obviously useful as intermediaries in various proofs.

My question is: does anyone understand how to actually program in them? I mean, Turing Machines, if I sit down and work through it, I can eventually design one to do something I want, and/or understand what's going on under the hood.

Contrast this to 2-tag systems, where I am lost. I think the most complex thing I was ever able to make without brute forcing it was one that added two numbers (well, concatenated two strings) together.

Does anyone have any advice on how to look at tag systems as a programming paradigm? Or are they just too chaotic to be intentionally used in that way?